# Get Exact String Between Two Strings in B4A

Tags: c#, android, regex, string

Help Me With This PLZ.
My input is:

```
   ("HI,How Are You?RANDOME TEXT,What About You?")
```

I Want my Output to be:

```
 ("RANDOME TEXT")
```

"RANDOME TEXT" can be every thing and it is not unique,How can I get a string between "How Are You?" and ",What About You?" in this example?
In C# We Use Regex.Match as I can remember but I can't do anything in b4a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get first appearance index of "?" character and get last appearance index of "," character and then get substring of that. Like this:

```
String s = "HI,How Are You?RANDOME TEXT,What About You?";
int first = s.indexOf("?");
int last = s.lastIndexOf(",");
String subString = s.substring(first,last);
```

and you get the string that you want.

Comment: I think you just correct this: 'String subString = s.SubString2(first,last + 1);'